# WordPress: check if user solve quiz in gravity forms

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm  have 2 forms in gravity forms, Now i need to check if user solve or Participate in solving the first question.
If user solve first question, he can go and see second question (this second question in another page).

if not, we need to show him custom message

How can do that!

Comment: did you check the documentation or tech support of gravity forms?

Comment: Post some screen shots of your question field and example answers so we know which gf field type you are using in order use correct gravity form filters